# Conditionally assign from part of an object

Tags: javascript

I think there's an elegant way to do this (maybe using destructuring), but I'm stumped so far.  I'd like to assign some of the keys and values from one object to another, conditionally based on a boolean.

```
function bigObject() {
  return { /* an object with lots of keys and values, lots */ }
} 

function myFunction(aBool) {
  // I want smallObject to be either empty or contain a subset of bigObject, based on aBool
  // here's where I am stuck
  let smallObject = aBool ? { keyA, keyB } = bigObject() : {};
}
```

JS complains that keyA is a reference error, and I can see how, even if I had this right, I'd just end up creating `keyA` and `keyB` variables, not `smallObject` as I want.

I know I can do this:

```
let smallObject = {};
if (aBool) {
  let bigObject = bigObject();
  smallObject.keyA = bigObject.keyA;
  smallObject.keyB = bigObject.keyB;
  smallObject.keyC = bigObject.keyC;
  // 5 of these
}
```

But that sure is a lot of stuff to write when I think there's a way I can write just the props names.

Comment: You just need to use the assigned variables, here using the comma operator to make it inline, but probably clearer to do it in multiple lines. `let smallObject = aBool ? ({ keyA, keyB } = bigObject(), { keyA, keyB }) : {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem to use temporary destructuring variables. Just use them again to build the target object. If you want it in one expression, you can use an inline function that performs the destructuring in its parameter variables, and then returns the new object:

```
let smallObject = aBool ? (
    ({ keyA, keyB }) => ({ keyA, keyB })
) (bigObject()) : {};
```

```js
const bigObject = () => ({ keyA: 1, keyB: 2, keyC: 3, keyD: 4});

let aBool = true;

let smallObject = aBool ? (
    ({ keyA, keyB }) => ({ keyA, keyB })
) (bigObject()) : {};

console.log(smallObject);
```

Comment: I had to stare at that for 2 minutes, but I get it!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that returns a destructured object.

```js
const bigObject = {
  keyA: 'a',
  keyB: 'b',
  keyC: 'c',
};

const getObj = (aBool) =>
  aBool
    ? (({ keyA, keyB }) => ({ keyA, keyB }))(bigObject)
    : {};

console.log(getObj(true));
```

Or you could write your own "plucking" function to return a new object based on the original:

```js
const bigObject = {
  keyA: 'a',
  keyB: 'b',
  keyC: 'c',
};

const pluck = (obj, callback) => callback(obj);

const getObj = (aBool) =>
  aBool
    ? pluck(bigObject, ({ keyA, keyB }) => ({ keyA, keyB }))
    : {};

console.log(getObj(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
if (aBool) smallObject = { ...smallObject, ...bigObject};
```

**Option 2**

```
if (aBool) {
   Object.entries(bigObject).forEach(([key, value]) => smallObject[key] = value);
}
```

Comment: BTW, as I reread this, I think it doesn't do what I hope for.  I only want some of the keys in big object. Thx for the help.